# What is the difference between a one sample t-test and sign test?

Tags: t-test, sign-test

If I've conducted an experiment with only 10 samples and the data acquired have some wide gap in values, what would I use from the two statistical method.

Here are my values sample values:

[image]

Comment: It is easier to provide useful answers when the question includes details of (1) what the experiment is and what the observations are, and (2) the type of inferences that are desired. Do you need a 'test'? Why not just plot the data and note the mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are mentioning t-tests and sign tests because you are interested in comparing some sort of measure of centrality. In which case the t-test compares the mean of the sample while the sign test compares the median. The t-test is a parametric test with more assumptions (such as normally distributed sample data for a one-sample test) but with more power. So if all assumptions hold you would use a t-test, otherwise look for alternatives. Also worth noting that with only 10 samples it will be hard to determine distribution.